# Odoo - two servers (and two databases) working as one

Tags: database, postgresql, odoo, database-replication

Is it possible to have two separate servers that would have their own database. But those databases would share same data (synchronize with each other).

For example there is one Odoo server in one end of the world and another in another end of the world (I mean real world :)). Any change that happens in one server database would automatically be reflected in another server database and vise versa.

I read that there is possibility to use postgresql database replication. And there is this cascading replication (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/warm-standby.html#CASCADING-REPLICATION) feature, which in theory should work similarly.

Does anyone have done something similar and could share their knowledge how to successfully implement such thing. Or it's not really possible or not worth it?

P.S. our client wants such thing, so users (in one end of the world) could have better connection because server would be closer to them. But I wonder about lag between these database replications, because of the distance and would it really increase performance this way.